# How to use device_map of huggingface on multiple GPUs?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, distributed, large-language-model

I encountered the following issues while using the `device_map` provided by Hugging Face for model parallel inference:

I am running the code from the example code provided by Hugging Face, which can be found at the GitHub address:https://github.com/akkikiki/huggingface_examples/blob/main/examples/load_flan_ul2.py

In the same code, as shown in Figure 1, it indicates that the code plans to use 4 GPUs. However, during the debugging process, I noticed that the model is only using 3 GPUs, as seen in the variables on the left side.

Furthermore, in the code, the maximum memory usage per GPU (except GPU0) is set to 16GB. However, as shown in Figure 2, the actual memory usage exceeds 20GB or even 30GB. Why is this happening?

Additionally, while continuing the debugging process, when executing `model.generate()`, the code does not output any results. When I run the code without debugging, directly using `python file_name.py`, I encounter the error shown in Figure 3.

I would like to understand the reasons behind these issues. Thank you very much!
[figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiQRz.png)
[figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNHcX.png)
[figure 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKm9r.png)

I have tried the code in huggingface blog, but the error still exist.